# Single quote around Macro Variable

Tags: sql, macros, sas, where-clause

I have a macro variable which has more than 1 observation like below.

```
%let age = 12,34,56;
%put &age;
```

Now I want to use the age as in my **where** parameter in proc sql.

```
proc sql;
select *
from family
where age in ("&age");
quit;
```

I have used **%bquote,%quote,%str()** and many more but not successful yet.

Comment: Why does the title say 'single quote', but you (sort-of-correctly) use double quotes?

Comment: True. Might need to change the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without any quotes at all (I assume age is a numeric variable).

And if age is a character one then you can re-write WHERE statement like this;

```
  where input(age, 8.) in (&age)
```

When you write

```
 "&age"
```

SAS creates single string with all values and commas inside, which is not what we need for IN operator.

*Added.*
This is my code that works:

```
%let age = 12,34,56;
%put &age;

data family;
  input age @@;
  datalines;
15 16 17 12 33 34 55 56
;
run;

proc sql;
  select *
  from family
  where age in (&age);
quit;
```

Comment: this should do it, no quotes on a numeric

Comment: When we create macro it automatically is considered as "Character". In this case AGE was character. I believe "cooma" is a big trouble here.

Comment: That's strange  - this code works for me. I'll add to the answer how I create the dataset itself.

Comment: I guess the problem is bunch of Macro's initiated in the same proc sql statement. I will post more relevant question statement. Since your code works fine and mine fails.

Comment: Sorry Dmitry. Your first solution was right. Input worked fine with some tweaks in the length parameter. Thanks again.